# Multiple cards in a row not spacing as expected

Tags: vmware-clarity

I've been experimenting with some of the sample code in the documentation, and in particular laying out three cards in a row.

When I cut'n paste the code into my component page I'm not getting the expected outcome.

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="alert alert-app-level">
    ...
  </div>
  <header class="header header-6">
    <div class="branding">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">
        <img alt="" src="assets/logo2.png" height="60">
        <span class="title">Good day</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-actions"></div>

    <form class="search">
      <label for="search_input">
        <input id="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Search for keywords...">
      </label>
    </form>

    <div class="header-actions">
      <clr-dropdown>
        <button class="nav-text" clrDropdownTrigger aria-label="open user profile">
          john.doe@vmware.com
          <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen clrPosition="bottom-right">
          <a href="..." clrDropdownItem>Preferences</a>
          <a href="..." clrDropdownItem>Log out</a>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
      </clr-dropdown>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card 1</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              ...
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card 2</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              ...
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card 3</h3>
            <p class="card-text">
              ...
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting three equally sized cards across the web page.  Instead I get...

[image]

Do I need to install Bootstrap for this to work?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you are missing one important element in your page structure. The Cards are good, but you need to add `<div class="content-area">` just inside of your `<div class="content-container">` element.

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area"> <!-- THIS IS MISSING -->
        <div class="clr-row">
            <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Card 1</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            ...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Card 2</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            ...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr-col-lg-4 clr-col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Card 3</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            ...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="..." class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Action 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make all cards in a row to have the same vertical size?

Comment: I would recommend to use CSS Grid instead of our grid classes to make the cards layout that way.